# Count every distinct tag

Tags: sql, tags, count, distinct

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag) AS tags, filename, COUNT(tag) AS count
FROM dados
GROUP BY filename
ORDER BY filename
```

I have that query which show me all the tags for each movie, without the repetitions tag. But now i want to show in front of each tag the number of repetitions. Something like this:
movie (20), train (50), etc.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subquery for this:

```
select filename, group_concat(tagstr separator ',') as tags,
       count(*) as NumDistinctTags,
       sum(cnt) as NumTags
from (select filename, tag,
             concat(tag, ' (', count(*), ')') as tagstr,
             count(*) as cnt
      from dados d
      group by filename, tag
     ) d
group by filename
order by filename
```

The inner query creates the string that you want for each tag.  The outer puts them together at the filename level.

I am assuming that you are using MySQL because of the group_concat.  In other dialects of SQL, the concat operator may be expressed differently.

Comment: I have to change the 'varchar' at the 3 line to char, to work ;)
Thank you.

Comment: @zppinto . . . I cannot see anything obviously wrong.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to SQL Fiddle where I am now, so alas I cannot readily test this.

Comment: Everything is fine now Gordon! :) I just need to change the "varchar" to "char" for it to work! ;)

Comment: @zppinto . . . I just learned something . . . MySQL does not support varchar() in the cast statement.  I don't like implicit conversions, but in this case, it might be easier to just leave out the cast.  "CONCAT" accepts integer arguments and converts them, implicitly, to strings.

Comment: @Gordon... Just one thing: How can i order by the more repetitions tags to the less ones?

Comment: You can add the ORDER BY clause to the expression:  group_concat(tagstr order by cnt desc separator ',').  You should find the documentation helpful for group_concat, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat.